# codeigniter 3 load models with composer

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i'm trying to load codeigniter 3 models with composer,
after composer install and setup and composer autoload setting to TRUE in config file
i have a json file

```
  "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "/home/vendor"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Core\\": "/home/application/core",
            "App\\Controllers\\": "/home/application/controllers",
            "App\\Models\\": "/home/application/models",
            "App\\Libraries\\": "/home/application/libraries",
            "App\\Interfaces\\": "/home/application/interfaces",
            "App\\": "/home/application/"
        }
    },
```

in core folder(application/core/BaseModel.php)

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

namespace App\Core;
class BaseModel extends \CI_Model {
}
```

and in models folder

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
namespace App\Models;
use App\Core\BaseModel;

class Welcome_model extends BaseModel {
}
```

then in a Welcome controller i try this:(Welcome.php)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use App\Models\Welcome_model;


class Welcome extends CI_Controler {

    public function index()
    {

        $welcome_model = new Welcome_model();
}
```

but nothing works, any ideas?
how can i call models in a controller like

```
$mymodel = New Model....();
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Your idea of how to use CodeIgniter and Composer are flawed. Yes, you can use Composer, and I do it all the time. You're just overthinking the autoloading of the model. For that you would just use config/autoload.php or $this->load->model(); If you are trying to achieve total autoloading through composer, why not just go with another framework? The problem with doing this in CI is that you would not benefit from adding the model to the CodeIgniter super object.

Comment: you just need to defind `App` and use `namespace` for all folder inside app, take a look at my slim skeleton https://github.com/jaredchu/Slim3-GAE-Skeleton